# Matplotlib errorbars horizontal lines/connecting lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I just created a bar chart with errorbars and wonder why a linear line is drawn from one errorbar to the next. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

[image: Bar Chart Picture:e]

The code:

```
for k in range(1,(len(Durchgansmarker)*2)+1):

if k<=int(len(Durchgansmarker)):

    globals()[f'rects{k}_error'] =axes_1.errorbar(x -Anzahl_Balken/2*width_bar+(k*width_bar)-width_bar/2  ,globals()[f'y_tr_mean_E{k}'], yerr=globals()[f'y_tr_std_E{k}'], capsize=5, ecolor="k", elinewidth=2,barsabove='False' ,zorder=4)#fmt="o", color="r"

    globals()[f'rects{k}'] = axes_1.bar(x -Anzahl_Balken/2*width_bar+(k*width_bar)-width_bar/2  ,globals()[f'y_tr_mean_E{k}'],width_bar, color=color_Bars[k-1],zorder=3)#,yerr=[globals()[f'y_tr_std_E{k}']]

else:

    globals()[f'rects{k}_error'] =axes_1.errorbar(x -Anzahl_Balken/2*width_bar+(k*width_bar)-width_bar/2  ,globals()[f'y_ge_mean_E{k-3}'], yerr=globals()[f'y_ge_std_E{k-3}'], capsize=5, ecolor="k", elinewidth=2,barsabove='False' ,zorder=4)#fmt="o", color="r"

    globals()[f'rects{k}'] = axes_1.bar(x -Anzahl_Balken/2*width_bar+(k*width_bar)-width_bar/2,globals()[f'y_ge_mean_E{k-3}'],width_bar, color=color_Bars[k-1],zorder=3)
```

Here are the y values for the bar and errorbar commands: [image: values]

Answer (score 1):

have found the solution in the meantime. Simply specify `linestyle=''` as argument when calling the `plt.errorbar` function. Then the connecting lines between the errorbars are not drawn (see figure).

In my case related to the origin question the function call is:

```
globals()[f'rects{k}_error'] =axes_1.errorbar(x -Anzahl_Balken/2*width_bar+(k*width_bar)-width_bar/2  ,globals()[f'y_tr_mean_E{k}'], yerr=globals()[f'y_tr_std_E{k}'], capsize=5, ecolor="k", elinewidth=2,barsabove='False' ,zorder=4,linestyle='')
```

[image: Bar_Chart]

Greetings